# How do I get variables from a class and put it into another class, and put it into a constructor?

Tags: c++, class, date, constructor

I'm having a bit of a problem here. Well I have an assignment in my class where we made 3 header files(.h files) and 3 .cpp files. The assignments were 
Person
Date 
and Time.

I will display them for you to see.

person.h

```
#include <iostream>
using  namespace std;
#ifndef PERSON
#define PERSON

class Person
{
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
public:
    Person();
    Person(string,string);
    void displayPerson();
};
#endif
```

person.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"
using namespace std;

Person::Person()
{
firstName=" ";
lastName=" ";
}
Person::Person(string fn, string ln)
{
firstName=fn;
lastName=ln;
}
void Person::displayPerson()
{
cout<<firstName<<", "<<lastName;
}
```

Date.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef DATE
#define DATE
class Date
{
private:
    string month;
    string day;
    string year;
public:
    Date();
    Date(string,string,string);
    void displayDate();
};
#endif // DATE
```

Date.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date::Date()
{
    month="01";
    day="01";
    year="2013";
}
Date::Date(string m,string d, string y)
{
    month=m;
    day=d;
    year=y;
}
void Date::displayDate()
{
    cout<<month<<"/"<<day<<"/"<<year;
}
```

Time.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef TIME
#define TIME
class Time
{
private:
    static const int MAXMIN=59;
    static const int MINMIN=0;
    static const int MAXHOUR=24;
    static const int MINHOUR=0;
    int militaryHours;
    int militaryMinutes;
    int standardHours;
    int standardMinutes;
    string AMPM;
public:
    Time(int);
    Time(int,int);
    void displayTime();
    void displayTime1();
};
#endif // TIME
```

Time.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"
using namespace std;

Time::Time(int mh)
{
    string zero="0";
    militaryHours=mh;

if (militaryHours>MAXHOUR || militaryHours<MINHOUR)
{
    militaryHours=MAXHOUR;
    standardHours=12;
}
else if(militaryHours>12 && militaryHours<MAXHOUR)
{
    standardHours=militaryHours-12;
    AMPM="P.M.";
}
else if(militaryHours<12 && militaryHours>=MINHOUR)
{
    standardHours=militaryHours;
    AMPM="A.M.";
}

cout<<"MILITARY TIME: "<<militaryHours<<":"<<zero<<zero<<" "<<AMPM;
cout<<"\nSTANDARD TIME: "<<standardHours<<":"<<zero<<zero<<" "<<AMPM;
}

Time::Time(int mh,int mm)
{
     string zero="0";
     militaryHours=mh;
     militaryMinutes=mm;

if (militaryHours>MAXHOUR || militaryHours<MINHOUR)
{
    militaryHours=MAXHOUR;
    standardHours=12;
}
else if(militaryHours>12 && militaryHours<=MAXHOUR)
{
    standardHours=militaryHours-12;
    AMPM="P.M.";
}
else if(militaryHours<12 && militaryHours>=MINHOUR)
{
    standardHours=militaryHours;
    AMPM="A.M.";
}
if(militaryMinutes>MAXMIN && militaryMinutes<MINMIN)
{
    militaryMinutes=MAXMIN;
}
else if(militaryMinutes<MAXMIN && militaryMinutes>MINMIN)
{
    standardMinutes=0;
    standardMinutes=militaryMinutes;
}
if(militaryMinutes<10 && militaryMinutes>=MINMIN)
{
    standardMinutes=0;
    standardMinutes=militaryMinutes;
    cout<<"MILITARY TIME: "<< militaryHours<<":"<<zero<<standardMinutes<<" "     <<AMPM;
    cout<<"\nSTANDARD TIME: "<<standardHours<<":"<<zero<<standardMinutes<<"     "<<AMPM;
}
else
{
    cout<<"MILITARY TIME: "<< militaryHours<<":"<<standardMinutes<<" "<<AMPM;
    cout<<"\nSTANDARD TIME: "<<standardHours<<":"<<standardMinutes<<" "<<AMPM;
}
}
```

ok so
person was to get the first name and last name of a person
Date was to get a date...month day year
Time was to ask a user for a time and to output military and standard time.

Now our teacher wants us to make a fourth class... named DentalAppointment.

This is what the assignment says

"Create  a  class named DentalAppointment. Include fields for patient data(using the existing Person class), the date(using the existing class), the time(using the existing Time class), and the duration of the appointment in minutes. Also, include a field that contains the ending  time for the appointment - this field will be calculated based on the start time and the duration using the Time class function that adds minutes to the time object. The DentalAppointment constructor requires a first and last name, a month,day, and year, and an hour and minute for the appointment. Allow a DentalApppointment to be constructed with or without and additional argument for duration and force the duration to 30 minutes when no argument is supplied. The constructor should not allow any appointment over 240 minutes. The constructor will calculate the appointment ending time base on the start time and duration. Create a display function for the DentalAppointment class. Write a main() function that loops at least three times prompting the user for DentalAppointment data and displaying the information. Use an initialization list for the constructor."

Ok here is where I am confused.

so basically I have to pass the values from Person,Date, Time to DentalAppointment.

so first I made a DentalAppointment class.

DentalAppointment.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "Time.h"
using  namespace std;

class DentalAppointment
{
private:

public:

};
```

I dont know what to put in the private and public parts. Do I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "Time.h"
using  namespace std;

class DentalAppointment
{
private:
    Person pFirstName;
    Person pLastName;
    Date appointmentMonth;
    Date appointmentDay;
    Date appointmentYear;
    Time appointmentHour;
    Time appointmentMinutes;
    int duration;
public:
    DentalAppointment();
    DentalAppointment(Person,Person,Date,Date,Date,Time,Time);
    DentalAppointment(Person,Person,Date,Date,Date,Time,Time,int);
    void showDentalAppointment();
};
```

if so then what do I put in for my cpp file?
should it be like this???

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "DentalAppointment.h"
using namespace std;

DentalAppointment::DentalAppointment()
{
    pFirstName=Person.firstName;
    pLastName=Person.lastName;
    appointmentMonth=Date.month;
    appointmentDay=Date.day;
    appointmentYear=Date.year;
    appointmentHour=Time.standardHours;
    appointmentMinutes=Time.standardMinutes;
}
DentalAppointment::DentalAppointment(Person fn,Person ln ,Date month,Date day,Date year,Time h,Time m)
{
    pFirstName=fn;
    pLastName=ln;
    appointmentMonth=month;
    appointmentDay=day;
    appointmentYear=y;
    appointmentHour=h;
    appointmentMinutes=m;
}

DentalAppointment::DentalAppointment(Person fn,Person ln ,Date month,Date      day,Date year,Time hours,Time minutes,int d)
 {
    pFirstName=fn;
    pLastName=ln;
    appointmentMonth=month;
    appointmentDay=day;
    appointmentYear=year;
    appointmentHour=hours;
    appointmentMinutes=minutes;
    duration=d;
}
```

please tell me if I am way off, or if im close. because calling private and public variables from different classes and putting them into different classes is confusing me. and putting them in constructors is killen me.... please help me!!!
Thank You!!!

I did what you did but now its "C:\Users\Ibrahim Munaser\Documents\c++\DentalAppointment\DentalAppointment.cpp|9|error: no matching function for call to 'Time::Time()'|".... I dont know what it means... im gonna send you my h and cpp file and see if you could find anything

Date.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "Time.h"
using  namespace std;

class DentalAppointment
{
    private:
    Person pFirstName;
    Person pLastName;
    Date appointmentMonth;
    Date appointmentDay;
    Date appointmentYear;
    Time appointmentHour;
    Time appointmentMinutes;
    int duration;
public:
    DentalAppointment(Person,Person,Date,Date,Date,Time,Time);
    DentalAppointment(Person,Person,Date,Date,Date,Time,Time,int);
    void showDentalAppointment();
};
```

Date.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include "DentalAppointment.h"
using namespace std;


DentalAppointment::DentalAppointment(Person fn,Person ln ,Date month,Date day,Date year,Time h,Time m)
{
    pFirstName=fn;
    pLastName=ln;
    appointmentMonth=month;
    appointmentDay=day;
    appointmentYear=y;
    appointmentHour=h;
    AppointmentMinutes=m;
}
DentalAppointment::DentalAppointment(Person fn,Person ln ,Date month,Date day,Date year,Time hours,Time minutes,int d)
{
    pFirstName=fn;
    pLastName=ln;
    appointmentMonth=month;
    appointmentDay=day;
    appointmentYear=year;
    appointmentHour=hours;
    AppointmentMinutes=minutes;
    duration=d;
}
```

Comment: Usually you put your header guards *before* any code and includes. A `Person` object represents a person and not a name, so it does not make sense to have 2 `Person` objects to represent the first and last names. You have 2 name parts, yet you are 1 person I assume!

Comment: Are you trying to *bury* us? Please reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: thats what im confused about :( not seeing whats going on when im doing          "Person person_"... im not sure how I would get firstname and last time from doing this :(

Comment: sorry about that... its first time asking a question on stackoverflow :(

Comment: ill make another question in a simple way.. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to build `DentalAppointment` from `Person`, `Date` and `Time` directly.  So more like:

```
class DentalAppointment {
    Person person_;
    Date date_;
    Time time_;
public:
    DentalAppointment(const Person& p, const Date& d , const Time& t) : person_(p), date_(d), time_(t) {}
    // other stuff
}
```

EDIT: To simplify the constructor, you start with:

```
DentalAppointment(Person p, Date d , Time t) {
     person_ = p;
     date_ = d;
     time_ = t;
}
```

This simply takes objects of `Person`, `Date` and `Time` and assigns them to your data members.  Then as you learn more C++ you end up at the given constructor above.  But here's a good place for you to start.

Comment: hahaha please dont go tooo advanced. In our class we are only started to learn about friend and overloaded operators. so for DentalAppointment(const Person& p, const Date&d , const Time* t) : {person_(p), date_(d), time_(t) {}...... i have no idea what is going on in there... im confused... could you please explain to this me as if you are tutoring me.. because im not that great in coding yet. like for "Person person_;" ......is "person_h" a variable or an object.?

Comment: wait... so now by doing what you did I can now access all variables like "firstName" and "lastName" from the persons class????

Comment: and what does the "_" stand for after each name???

Comment: 1) No, you have to adjust those classes to meet the needs of your `DentalAppointment` class 2) Appended `_` is just a convention for data members.  There are many, some like to prefix them ith `m_`.  It makes it clear that they are `private` data member of that class.

Comment: Or, you might be able to meet all those needs with your `public` member functions like `void Person::displayPerson()`.  You certainly can write a `displayAppointment` member function with only them

Comment: I did what you did but now its "C:\Users\Ibrahim Munaser\Documents\c++\DentalAppointment\DentalAppointment.cpp|9|error: no matching function for call to 'Time::Time()'|".... I dont know what it means... im gonna send you my h and cpp file and see if you could find anything.

Comment: haha we just started learning this... so ill try harder and get it hopefully.

Comment: Add all of this to your question, that way we can all read it easily.